# sort week days by first day of work

Tags: c#, globalization

is there a better way of rearange the

```
DateTimeFormat.DayNames
```

acording to the

```
DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
```

so that if

```
DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = 1
```

dayNames containts mon,tue,wed, ...
insted of son,mon,tue, ...
I'm currently using:

```
CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
string[] DayNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames;
int FirstDayOfWeek = (int)culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
string[] tempdays = new string[7];
for (int i = 0; i <= DayNames.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    tempdays[i] = DayNames[i == 0 ? FirstDayOfWeek : 
                           (i == 6 - FirstDayOfWeek ? 6 : 
                           i > 6 - FirstDayOfWeek ? 0 != (6 - (i + (FirstDayOfWeek - 1))) ? 
                           (6 - (i + (FirstDayOfWeek - 1))) * -1 : 
                           6 - (i + (FirstDayOfWeek - 1)) : i + FirstDayOfWeek)];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've effectively implemented to modulo operator, so you can simplify your expression to

```
tempdays[i] = DayNames[ (FirstDayOfWeek + i) % 7 ];
```